# What are symbolic addresses? Symbolic Address/Logical Address vs. Relocatable address

Tags: memory-management, operating-system

In memory management, symbolic address of the source program in disk are bound by compiler to relocatable addresses(which are the instruction addresses relative to each other). Then the linker binds the relocatable address to absolute addresses(which are the physical addresses allocated in main memory). However, what are symbolic addresses?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not usually correct:

> Then the linker binds the relocatable address to absolute addresses

A linker generally creates relative addresses so that the image can be placed at different places in memory.

> However, what are symbolic addresses?

Generally, one call it a "symbolic reference." A symbol can stand for an address but is not an address itself.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the last part.
How are the symbols generated from absolute addresses in the disk, storing the source code?

Comment: Generated where? And it's generally not absolute addresses.

Comment: Can you please explain symbolic address vs relocatable address format. Thanks
Logical address is generated by the CPU